# I want to replace an empty node in xml with python

Tags: python, xml, writexml

**I want to replace the closing `<category/>` to `Passenger cars </category>`  with python. I just need to add "Passenger cars" between the category opening and closing xml tags**

```
        categories=xml.getElementsByTagName('category')[0].toxml()
        if categories=='<category/>':
            categories=categories.replace('<category/>','<category>Passenger cars</category>')
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to overwrite only this one node in xml. When i do it
Tree.writexml (codecs.open (path + "MOD _" + file, 'w', "utf-8"))
Nothing changes in xml.